# How to clone iPad 1 to other iPad 1

Tags: ios, ipad

I need to transfer all apps from iPad 1 (without cellular) to another iPad 1 (with cellular). My eldest son plays some child's app on my old iPad 1. My younger son grown up so he want's to play this games too. As I have another one iPad 1 I wanted to install this apps on it. But they are don't support iOS 5 any longer.
So I'm looking way to clone old iPad.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to iTunes on your Mac or PC.

Broadley speaking, the steps would be:

1. Launch iTunes on your Mac or PC
2. Connect the first iPad to your computer
3. iTunes should recognise that your iPad is connected and will display an iPad icon
4. Click on the iPad icon and view the Summary screen
5. You'll see a **Backups** section. Click on the <kbd>Backup now</kbd> button to make a full backup of the iPad to your computer. This may take some time.
6. Once completed, connect the other iPad to your computer
7. Repeat Steps 3 & 4 above
8. In the same **Backups** section, click on the <kbd>Restore Backup...</kbd> button
9. You'll now have the option to restore from the backup you just made to your other iPad. This also may take some time.

Further reading:

- [How to back up your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977)
- [Restore your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch from a backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204184)

Comment: will backup/restore thing work for slightly different ipads (with and without cellular)?

will iTunes handle two ipads with the same name? will sync work correctly?

Comment: Yes, it should all work fine. The only time you may have a problem is if the first iPad has a version of iOS installed that's different to the second iPad. In that case you'll get an error saying that you can't restore the backup to that iPad, or a message saying the second iPad has to be updated first. This all depends on your personal circumstances - but there's no risk because you're creating a backup of the first iPad (which remains intact) and your second iPad will either be restored from the backup or it won't (in which case it just remains as is).

Answer (score 0):

You could use iTunes to take a backup of original iPad and restore it on the other iPad.

Note: There's no version of the iPad without WiFi.

Comment: i'm sorry i mistaken, first iPad don't have cellular capabilities, edited original post